# Clickable Image Embed Code

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering if someone knows the best (or most secure) way to allow external sites to embed a clickable image which redirects back to my site?

I know I could use an absolute path in the src with plain HTML but is that better than say a Javascript solution?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "secure"? You want to ensure that it leads to nowhere other than your website?

Comment: What's wrong with a simple link?  Rather than asking for a specific solution, can you clue us in on the problem you're trying to solve?  You will get far more useful answers that way.

Comment: I guess I mean secure in the sense that I am opening access to an image which is hosted on my server. I know people can get this data anyway and can link to anywhere they want but I guess just checking if there are best practices around this type of thing. Cheers

Comment: I am basically generating an embed code from the members area which will have an href pointing to their profile page and an image which will be hosted on the server. That way a member can copy the code and paste on their own site. Hope that answers your question.

Comment: @KerePuki I can't think of any security implications for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="http://your-site.com">
  <img src="http://your-site.com/imgs/someimage.png" >
</a>
```